# SpringSecurityContext is not passed when app is working in pods GKE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, kubernetes-pod

I need to get a UserDetails in servlet filter. So I'm getting it from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() like this -

```
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
     UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
        .getPrincipal();
...
}
```

Locally the user is fetched from the Security context, but when deploying the app to GKE the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is null.

I've tried to configure SecurityContextHolder to MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL like this, but it didn't help

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityContextHolderConfig {
  public SecurityContextHolderConfig() {
    SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
  }
}
```

still SecurityContext is not passed to the Filter in a pod.
(app packaging is WAR)
configuration - Spring oauth2-client with JWT authentication (in the header)

Comment: I don't think changing the strategy is the way to go. What's your security configuration? Are you sure that whatever your authentication is, it's reaching your application? Like a cookie, a header?

Comment: it is a Spring oauth2-client with JWT authentication (in the header). 
It is working locally fine. That is why it is confusing.

Comment: I was trying to get the authentication JWT from headers but the header was also erased (in GKE), locally everything is working.

Comment: @ArtemEduardov Do you use a reverse proxy or a load balancer? Maybe it deletes the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
 @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest =
    (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

    Principal userPrincipal = httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal();
```